# Change App Store currency

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, itunes-store

I have recently changed the App Store region to South Korea, as I'm currently living here. I'd like to know if there is any way to change the currency of the App store without changing the country of the store?

I think it cannot be done but my husband insists that I have to change it because Apple charges more in KRW than USD.

I am using an iPhone 7.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to know if there is any way to change the currency of the App store without changing the country of the store?

The App Store uses the currency of the country which you are using to access the App Store. It is **not possible** to choose the currency at your will, i.e. using South Korea App Store while choosing to pay in USD.

The difference is rates appears due to the exchange rates used by Apple.